# LinkedList ToString Output

Tags: java, list, linked-list, tostring

I am building some test just to get my self familiar with linked lists.

I am trying to print out the linkedlist objects however I am not getting any result. It may very well be I am doing something that's rather basic wrong I don't know.

Node.java

```
public class Node<E> {
    E data;
    Node<E> next;

    //Constructor One
    /** Creates a new node with a null next field.
     * @param dataItem The data stored.
     */
    Node(E dataItem){
        data = dataItem;
        next = null;
    }

    //Constructor Two
    /** Creates a new node that references another node.
     * @param dataItem //the data stored
     * @nodeRef nodRef //The node referenced by new node.
     */
    Node(E dataItem, Node<E> nodeRef){
        data = dataItem;
        next = nodeRef;

    }
}
```

SlinkedList.java

```
/** Class to represent a linked list with a link from each node to the next node
 * 
 * @author Study
 *
 * @param <E>
 */
public class SlinkedList<E> {


    // Reference to head Node
    private Node<E> head = null;

    //The number of Items in list
    private int size;

    /** Add an Item to the front of a list.
     * @param item the item to be added*/
    public void addFirst(E item){
        head = new Node<E>(item, head);
        size++;
    }

    /** Add a node after a given node
     * 
     * @param node //The node preceding the new item.
     * @param item //The item to insert.
     */
    public void addAfter(Node<E> node, E item){
        node.next = new Node<E>(item, node.next);
        size++;
    }

    /** Remove the node after a given node
     * @param node, the node before the one to be removed
     * @returns the data from the removed node or null if there is no node to remove.
     */
    //This will work for all nodes except the first one.
    public E removeAfter(Node<E> node){
        Node<E> temp = node.next;
        if(temp != null){
            //Nodes next(node before node to remove) equals temps next(the node after node to remove) 
            node.next = temp.next;
            size--;
            return temp.data;   
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        Node<E> nodeRef = head;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while(nodeRef != null){
            result.append(nodeRef.data);
            if(nodeRef.next != null){
                result.append("==>");
            }
            nodeRef = nodeRef.next; // Advance down the list.
        }
        return result.toString();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SlinkedList<String> test = new SlinkedList<String>();
        Node<String> tom = new Node<String>("Tom");
        test.addFirst("AddFirstOne");
        test.addFirst("AddFirstTwo");
        test.toString();
    }
}
```

I am expecting a print out of Tom, AddFirstOne, AddFirstTwo from the toString() method.

Upon running I just get an empty console output. Once again I am new to LinkedLists, I have done everything I can think of correctly to get an output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see you adding the first node to your linked list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little please? I am using add First method in the main to do such... I think.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the list, you are just calling the method which returns a `String`. Change

```
test.toString(); // Doesn't print, just returns a String
```

to

```
System.out.println(test); // toString() of test is automatically called
```